# How can I choose which guns to permanently unlock?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I am now prestige level 7.
The first three levels gave me a choice what I wanted to permanently unlock. After that I never got a choice, it just automatically picks something.

How can I make it so that I can choose myself instead of this automatic system?